# How do I make a D-flip flop down counter count synchronously?

Tags: flipflop

I know how to do it with a JK Flip Flop, but not too sure how to do it with a D Flip Flop.

Also, is it possible to mix D-FF and JK-FF and make it count synchronously? If so, how?

Comment: Synchronous counters using D flip flops ?

Comment: Simply drive all flip-flops from the same clock. The resulting counter will, by definition, be a synchronous counter.

Comment: To re-phase what @WhatRoughBeast commented, drive all 'CLK' pins at the same time from the same clock. 'D' inputs must be stable before rising edge of clock.

Comment: If the JK inputs are set to logic '1', it will toggle 101010, etc, at the outputs. Acts like a gated version of a D type flip-flop.

Comment: Look at the diagrams of counters like the 74HC163. I do not think it wise to mix JK and D type flip-flops. A little research would have saved you much time-and our time. A link to help: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT163.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between D and JK flip flops is input gating. So if you know how to do it with JKs, it's trivial to modify it to use Ds with 'JK' input gating. Once you have a working D implementation, it should be possible to simplify out the additional input gating.

It's an exercise worth going through, as when you've finished, you'll go 'Aha!'. You'll realise that it would have been far simpler to forget the JK implementation, start with a description of what a counter should do on each clock edge, and synthesise it directly in Ds.

Comment: "it would have been far simpler to forget the JK implementation" needs explanation. Calculating the input logic for a D FF is easier than for a JK, but the resulting logic may be more complex in terms of gates per input. Depends on the logic required.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I think it's about right, given that the OP didn't put up a diagram of the JK they knew.